# Postgres SQL Query Distinct / Group By

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I migrated my database from SQLite to Postgres.
Before with SQlite I was able to eleminiate duplicates in my query output based on an ORDER BY followed by GROUP BY. The order by is required because I do some calculation on the data.

Lets assume I have the following to tables
T1 Option

| Symbol | date | strike | lastprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-08-05 | 20 | 1 |
| A | 2022-08-04 | 20 | 1.1 |
| B | 2022-08-05 | 18 | 2 |
| B | 2022-08-04 | 18 | 2.1 |
| A | 2022-08-05 | 21 | 1.1 |
| A | 2022-08-05 | 22 | 1.2 |
| B | 2022-08-05 | 18.5 | 1 |
| B | 2022-08-05 | 19 | 1.2 |

T2 Stock

| Symbol | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-08-05 | 19 |
| A | 2022-08-04 | 19.5 |
| B | 2022-08-05 | 18.5 |
| B | 2022-08-04 | 18.4 |

I run the following query

```
select s.price/o.strike as CalculatedValue, *
from "Stock" s  
inner join "Option" o 
on (o.symbol = s.symbol) and s."date" = o."date"
WHERE 
o."date" = (select x."date" FROM "Option" x where x."date" notnull ORDER BY x."date"  DESC LIMIT 1)
order by CalculatedValue desc
```

The output is

| calculatedValue | symbol | date | price | symbol | date | strike | lastprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0277777777777777 | B | 2022-08-05 | 18.5 | B | 2022-08-05 | 18.0 | 2.0 |
| 1.0 | B | 2022-08-05 | 18.5 | B | 2022-08-05 | 18.5 | 1.0 |
| 0.9736842105263158 | B | 2022-08-05 | 18.5 | B | 2022-08-05 | 19.0 | 1.2 |
| 0.95 | A | 2022-08-05 | 19.0 | A | 2022-08-05 | 20.0 | 1.0 |
| 0.9047619047619048 | A | 2022-08-05 | 19.0 | A | 2022-08-05 | 21.0 | 1.1 |
| 0.8636363636363636 | A | 2022-08-05 | 19.0 | A | 2022-08-05 | 22.0 | 1.2 |

what I need is the following

| calculatedValue | symbol | date | price | symbol | date | strike | lastprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0277777777777777 | B | 2022-08-05 | 18.5 | B | 2022-08-05 | 18.0 | 2.0 |
| 0.95 | A | 2022-08-05 | 19 | A | 2022-08-05 | 20.0 | 1.0 |

With SQLite I just uses group by s.symbol, in postgres this gives me an error.
Also I tried with a distinct on subquery which completely ignores my ORDER BY...

Any idea how this can be done )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use the partition by (s.symbol) in the query with ORDER BY ( calulated price) desc and with the filter with the value 1 so the you can get what you need

```
select * from (
select row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY s.symbol ORDER BY (s.price/o.strike) desc) as ord, s.price/o.strike as CalculatedValue,s.symbol,s.date,price,strike,lastprice
from "Stock" s  
inner join "Option" o 
on (o.symbol = s.symbol) and s."date" = o."date"
WHERE 
o."date" = (select x."date" FROM "Option" x where x."date" notnull ORDER BY x."date"  DESC LIMIT 1) 
) as drt where ord=1

order by CalculatedValue desc
```